# Historical trend lines built with array and loop - strange issue with order of crossings of lines with varip counter - Tradingview - Pinescript

Tags: arrays, loops, for-loop, pine-script, pine-script-v5

so I have an interesting issue. I put together a script, which draws historical trend lines using array and a loop. I then try to catch when each of the line is crossed and have an order of crosses, for that I use a varip counter. Everything works fine when there is one line crossing during 1 LIVE candle.

When there is multiple crossings during 1 LIVE candle - it becomes sort of random. Sometimes it works and shows me correct order of the crossings - 1) > 2) > 3), sometimes the order of crossings is opposite - 3) > 2) > 1), sometimes completely random -  2) > 1) > 3) > 4).

I opened a case with TradingVIew support and they suggested to revert the loop (for array_index = 0 to 24 >>> for array_index = 0 to 24) of the array, inside which everything happens. After I have done that - in some places the problem becomes fixed and the order becomes correct, while in other places the problem occurs...

It does not matter what direction the price is going or the color of the historical trend line that is crossed (red/green - red uses ta.pivothigh, green uses ta.pivotlow for pivot points to draw the trend lines in the beginning) and so far I cannot find what actually causes the issue...

If I could isolate the issue, I could add an if statement and then just run 2 loops per each condition so that such out of order issue would not happen, but so far I cannot determine the logic of the problem.

Here is a chart screenshot where you can clearly see the correct count for red candle on the left and incorrect(backwards) for both of the green candles on the right (the loop here is: for array_index = 0 to 24 | if I switch the loop to for array_index = 24 to 0: red candle count becomes incorrect and green candles become correct):
[See Screenshot Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrecV.png)

Or here: https://www.tradingview.com/x/cIEEXSAZ/

Those are the same trend lines and the only difference is: price direction and I have verified identical issues, with both directions of the price, so direction of the price should not be the issue here...

Here is a full code:

```
//@version=5
indicator("auto-trend-lines-varIP-testing", 
 overlay=true, max_lines_count=500, max_labels_count=500, max_boxes_count=500, max_bars_back=1500, precision=5)

leftbars = input.int(5, minval=1, title='Auto TrendLines: pivot detection: Left Bars')
rightbars = input.int(5, minval=1, title='Auto TrendLines: pivot detection: Right Bars')

// Pivots
ph = ta.pivothigh(high, leftbars, rightbars)
pl = ta.pivotlow(low, leftbars, rightbars)
// High
phv1 = ta.valuewhen(ph, high[rightbars], 0)
phb1 = ta.valuewhen(ph, bar_index[rightbars], 0)
phv2 = ta.valuewhen(ph, high[rightbars], 1)
phb2 = ta.valuewhen(ph, bar_index[rightbars], 1)
// Low
plv1 = ta.valuewhen(pl, low[rightbars], 0)
plb1 = ta.valuewhen(pl, bar_index[rightbars], 0)
plv2 = ta.valuewhen(pl, low[rightbars], 1)
plb2 = ta.valuewhen(pl, bar_index[rightbars], 1)

// TRENDLINE CODE
// --------------
get_slope(x1, x2, y1, y2) =>
    m = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)
    m

get_y_intercept(m, x1, y1) =>
    b = y1 - m * x1
    b

get_y(m, b, ts) =>
    Y = m * ts + b
    Y

// Resistance variables
int res_x1 = na
float res_y1 = na
int res_x2 = na
float res_y2 = na

// Support variables
int sup_x1 = na
float sup_y1 = na
int sup_x2 = na
float sup_y2 = na

// Resistance
res_x1 := ph ? phb1 : res_x1[1]
res_y1 := ph ? phv1 : res_y1[1]
res_x2 := ph ? phb2 : res_x2[1]
res_y2 := ph ? phv2 : res_y2[1]

res_m = get_slope(res_x1, res_x2, res_y1, res_y2)
res_b = get_y_intercept(res_m, res_x1, res_y1)
res_y = get_y(res_m, res_b, bar_index)

// Support
sup_x1 := pl ? plb1 : sup_x1[1]
sup_y1 := pl ? plv1 : sup_y1[1]
sup_x2 := pl ? plb2 : sup_x2[1]
sup_y2 := pl ? plv2 : sup_y2[1]

sup_m = get_slope(sup_x1, sup_x2, sup_y1, sup_y2)
sup_b = get_y_intercept(sup_m, sup_x1, sup_y1)
sup_y = get_y(sup_m, sup_b, bar_index)

//// ARRAY - history trend lines ////
var int [] phb1_arr = array.new_int(25, 2)
var float [] phv1_arr = array.new_float(25, 2)
var int [] res_x1_arr = array.new_int(25, 2)
var float [] res_y1_arr = array.new_float(25, 2)
var int [] res_x2_arr = array.new_int(25, 2)
var float [] res_y2_arr = array.new_float(25, 2)

var int [] plb1_arr = array.new_int(25, 2)
var float [] plv1_arr = array.new_float(25, 2)
var int [] sup_x1_arr = array.new_int(25, 2)
var float [] sup_y1_arr = array.new_float(25, 2)
var int [] sup_x2_arr = array.new_int(25, 2)
var float [] sup_y2_arr = array.new_float(25, 2)

// Push pivots high and low into an array every time new pivots appear, array.push pushes element at the end of the array every time it "happens"
if ph
    array.insert(phb1_arr, 0, phb1)
    array.insert(phv1_arr, 0, phv1)
    array.insert(res_x1_arr, 0, res_x1)
    array.insert(res_y1_arr, 0, res_y1)
    array.insert(res_x2_arr, 0, res_x2)
    array.insert(res_y2_arr, 0, res_y2)
if pl
    array.insert(plb1_arr, 0, plb1)
    array.insert(plv1_arr, 0, plv1)
    array.insert(sup_x1_arr, 0, sup_x1)
    array.insert(sup_y1_arr, 0, sup_y1)
    array.insert(sup_x2_arr, 0, sup_x2)
    array.insert(sup_y2_arr, 0, sup_y2)

// Declare the coordinates varibales which will be assigned coordinates from array
int phb1_from_array = 0
float phv1_from_array = 0.0
int res_x1_from_array = 0
float res_y1_from_array = 0.0
int res_x2_from_array = 0
float res_y2_from_array = 0.0

int plb1_from_array = 0
float plv1_from_array = 0.0
int sup_x1_from_array = 0
float sup_y1_from_array = 0.0
int sup_x2_from_array = 0
float sup_y2_from_array = 0.0

// Initiate the array loop
for array_index = 0 to 24
    if array.size(phb1_arr) > 0 and array.size(phv1_arr) > 0 and array.size(plb1_arr) > 0 and array.size(plv1_arr) > 0 and array.size(res_x1_arr) > 0 and
     array.size(res_y1_arr) > 0 and array.size(res_x2_arr) > 0 and array.size(res_y2_arr) > 0 and array.size(sup_x1_arr) > 0 and 
     array.size(sup_y1_arr) > 0 and array.size(sup_x2_arr) > 0 and array.size(sup_y2_arr) > 0
        phb1_from_array := array.get(phb1_arr, array_index)
        phv1_from_array := array.get(phv1_arr, array_index)
        res_x1_from_array := array.get(res_x1_arr, array_index)
        res_y1_from_array := array.get(res_y1_arr, array_index)
        res_x2_from_array := array.get(res_x2_arr, array_index)
        res_y2_from_array := array.get(res_y2_arr, array_index)

        plb1_from_array := array.get(plb1_arr, array_index)
        plv1_from_array := array.get(plv1_arr, array_index)
        sup_x1_from_array := array.get(sup_x1_arr, array_index)
        sup_y1_from_array := array.get(sup_y1_arr, array_index)
        sup_x2_from_array := array.get(sup_x2_arr, array_index)
        sup_y2_from_array := array.get(sup_y2_arr, array_index)

    // Re-calculate the trend lines stuff per newly grabbed coordinates from array
    res_m_from_array = get_slope(res_x1_from_array, res_x2_from_array, res_y1_from_array, res_y2_from_array)
    res_b_from_array = get_y_intercept(res_m_from_array, res_x1_from_array, res_y1_from_array)
    res_y_from_array = get_y(res_m_from_array, res_b_from_array, bar_index)

    sup_m_from_array = get_slope(sup_x1_from_array, sup_x2_from_array, sup_y1_from_array, sup_y2_from_array)
    sup_b_from_array = get_y_intercept(sup_m_from_array, sup_x1_from_array, sup_y1_from_array)
    sup_y_from_array = get_y(sup_m_from_array, sup_b_from_array, bar_index)

    // Draw the trend lines per coordinates/calculations grabbed from array, previous and all the history ones captured by the array
    //high (red) | per ARRAY
    red_line_arr = line.new(phb1_from_array, phv1_from_array, bar_index, res_y_from_array, color=color.rgb(143, 54, 54, 50), 
     extend=extend.none, width=5)
    //high (red) | per ARRAY | cross catch
    red_line_arr_coordinates = line.get_price(red_line_arr, bar_index)
    //line.delete(pivot_connector_high_arr[1])

    //low (green) | per ARRAY
    green_line_arr = line.new(plb1_from_array, plv1_from_array, bar_index, sup_y_from_array, color=color.rgb(9, 134, 36, 50), 
     extend=extend.none, width=5)
    //low (green) | per ARRAY | cross catch
    green_line_arr_coordinates = line.get_price(green_line_arr, bar_index)
    //line.delete(pivot_connector_low_arr[1])

    varip int position_order_counter = 0
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // POSITION OPEN | LONG (red)
    if open > red_line_arr_coordinates and low <= red_line_arr_coordinates and high > red_line_arr_coordinates
        red_line_arr_cross_lbl = label.new(bar_index, red_line_arr_coordinates, text="red(↑)|price:" + 
         str.tostring(math.round(red_line_arr_coordinates, 2)) + "|Count:" + 
         str.tostring(position_order_counter), style=label.style_label_up, 
         color=color.rgb(193, 122, 0), textcolor=color.white, size=size.normal)
        position_order_counter += 1
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // POSITION OPEN | SHORT (red)
    if open < red_line_arr_coordinates and high >= red_line_arr_coordinates and low < red_line_arr_coordinates
        red_line_arr_cross_lbl = label.new(bar_index, red_line_arr_coordinates, text="red(↓)|price:" + 
         str.tostring(math.round(red_line_arr_coordinates, 2)) + "|Count:" + 
         str.tostring(position_order_counter), style=label.style_label_down, 
         color=color.rgb(193, 122, 0), textcolor=color.white, size=size.normal)
        position_order_counter += 1
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // POSITION OPEN | LONG (green)
    if open > green_line_arr_coordinates and low <= green_line_arr_coordinates and high > green_line_arr_coordinates
        green_line_arr_cross_lbl = label.new(bar_index, green_line_arr_coordinates, text="grn(↑)|price:" + 
         str.tostring(math.round(green_line_arr_coordinates, 2)) + "|Count:" + 
         str.tostring(position_order_counter), style=label.style_label_up, 
         color=color.rgb(70, 112, 201), textcolor=color.white, size=size.normal)
        position_order_counter += 1
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // POSITION OPEN | SHORT (green)
    if open < green_line_arr_coordinates and high >= green_line_arr_coordinates and low < green_line_arr_coordinates
        green_line_arr_cross_lbl = label.new(bar_index, green_line_arr_coordinates, text="grn(↓)|price:" + 
         str.tostring(math.round(green_line_arr_coordinates, 2)) + "|Count:" + 
         str.tostring(position_order_counter), style=label.style_label_down, 
         color=color.rgb(70, 112, 201), textcolor=color.white, size=size.normal)
        position_order_counter += 1
```

Comment: This is way too much code. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @vitruvius, Hi, sorry about that, I did not realize I left a bunch of irrelevant stuff in the code, I just cleaned it up to as minimal as possible. Thanks!